Install .Net core 6.0.0 and Windows Desktop runtime 6.0.33 using online setup in WiX
I am using WiX to create an installer for my wpf application (I am new to this). I need to detect and install the .Net core 6.0.0 and Windows Desktop runtime 6.0.33 using online setup. Shipping offline setups with the WiX installer increases it's size and makes the users who already have the frameworks to download a large installer. I need to use online installers for these two.
Here is my code using offline setups:
    <Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="NetCoreInstaller">
              <ExePackage Id="NetCoreInstaller"
          SourceFile="dotnet-runtime-6.0.30-win-x64.exe"
          Vital="yes"
          DownloadUrl="http://localhost:59854/Desktop/dotnetfx40_client_x86_x64.exe"
          Compressed="yes"
          UninstallArguments="/uninstall"
          InstallArguments="/quiet"
          DetectCondition="NETCORE60FOUND" />
        <ExePackage Id="WindowsDesktopRuntime"
        SourceFile="windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.33-win-x64.exe"
        Vital="yes"
        DownloadUrl="https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/0f71eaf1-ce85-480b-8e11-c3e2725b763a/9044bfd1c453e2215b6f9a0c224d20fe/dotnet-sdk-6.0.100-win-x64.exe"
        Compressed="yes"
        UninstallArguments="/uninstall"
        InstallArguments="/quiet"
        DetectCondition="WINDOWSDESKTOP60FOUND" />
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <Property Id="NETCORE60FOUND">
        <RegistrySearch Id="NetCore60"
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedfx\Microsoft.NETCore.App"
        Name="6.0.0"
        Type="raw" />
    </Property>
    <Property Id="WINDOWSDESKTOP60FOUND">
        <RegistrySearch Id="WindowsDesktop60"
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedfx\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App"
        Name="6.0.0"
        Type="raw" />
    </Property>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="NetCore60Search" After="AppSearch" />
        <Custom Action="WindowsDesktop60Search" After="AppSearch" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Fragment>


Detecting should be the same as you already have. As far as I can tell, there are not online "installers" you can bundle in your application, but there are some pretty straightforward online install options.
With internet access, you can either have your installer run a winget command, or embed the dotnet-install powershell script into your installer and have it run that. Both of those should achieve an online install without packaging a bulky installer.
These options are explained and the script download is available at
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0 for net 6.
To run either in WiX, you can execute PowerShell commands using something like this FROM AN MSI. I don't think you can run either from the bundle.wxs itself. If you really need to do it from the bundle, you can always make a custom msi to chain (this would essentially be just making a super lightweight online installer yourself) or handle it in your WPF project. Both should be quite straightforward to implement :)
